# How to lower batch file permissions?

Tags: batch-file

my X.bat file is running with elevation and that's ok. But I need to find a command or a way to stop the elevation at some point in this bat (a certain line). The opposite of elevate.exe.
I don't mind to run instead a second Z.bat file as long as there is a way to run it without elevation. by default a bat file inherits the elevation rights from its parent, so I need to force somehow the non-elevation.

Comment: Could you use `runas` to do this?

Comment: Thank you. it solved my problem.